# How can I get the size of the file compressed in a lzo file without decompress it?

Tags: hadoop, lzo

I want to get the size of the file compressed in lzo files in hdfs, but I don't want to decompress the file. The file is very large, it takes a long time to download it to my PC.

Answer (score 0):

try lzop --list . 
You can ignore the rest of this message.